# awesome push notification with fcm

Tags: flutter, dart

i am lost at some point,
i am try to figure out how to use this plugin [plugin here](https://pub.dev/packages/awesome_notifications)
what should use to reply this:

this is working on fcm fine but i am trying to switch from fcm because of the reply like whatsApp

```
FirebaseMessaging.onMessage.listen
FirebaseMessaging.onMessageOpenedApp.listen
FirebaseMessaging.instance
.getInitialMessage()
.then((RemoteMessage message) {
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use action button:

```
AwesomeNotifications().createNotification(
          content: NotificationContent(
              id: 10,
              channelKey: 'basic_channel',
              title: 'Action button title',
              body: 'Simple body',
              
              ),
          actionButtons: [
            NotificationActionButton(
                key: "REPLY",
                label: "Reply",
                autoCancel: true,
                enabled: true,
                buttonType: ActionButtonType.InputField,
                icon: "resource://drawable/logo"),
          ],
        );
```

Comment: so how can you call a function immediately user press the button send.

Comment: you can show local notification using above code.